# How to fetch data from two different tables?

Tags: asp.net

Good noon to every one
my query is that i have one table name Purchase&Sales and two different field 
Purchase
Sales
the data which will be in Purchase text box will be fetch from Total purchase table
and the data will be in sales table will be fetch from Total Sales Table
means the both Value will come from different table to one table
So please Give me a syntax or some idea
Hoping for your Great and positive response

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: You can use join in query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(Purchase) Result from PurchaseTable
union all
select sum(Sales) Result from SalesTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JOIN or try with ForeignKey concept if any.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     S.Total, -- selecting from one table
    P.Total -- selecting from another table
FROM
    Sales S
INNER JOIN -- inner join if you can or similar
    Purchase P
ON
   S.PurchaseId = P.ID
```

see here for more info http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-query-multiple-tables/